# modify the input string to look like twitter's tweet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, string, twitter

this is how my twitter clone tweet looks like

[image: its very simple and basic]

sorry for spacing mistake here I can not mention user and hashtag and create a link for them like original twitter

and I was trying to make it more like original twitter like tweet

[image]

How can I make my twitter clone tweet look more like original twitter clone. I want that blue color like mentions and hashtags

Thank you for your solutions

Comment: Did you try the `<pre>` tag ? To keep the text formatting as `\n`

Comment: you can use regex to catch hashtags and usernames, then use anchor or link if you use react router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert the string to array using `string.split()` method.

Then customize the words you want to edit with `array.map()` method.

then I used `<YourComponent dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: yourStringContainingHTML }} />`

It worked for me.